# Securely give PHP entire root access?

Tags: php, security, nginx, ssh, root

I am developing a CMS and the tool I use for developing the CMS is almost entirely the CMS itself (almost entirely is not good enough, as I am developing tools within my CMS to automate everything I can). It would help a great deal if I could provide myself with entire root access via PHP and even perform tasks such as restarting Nginx directly from my CMS.

Security has to be the most important consideration to everything I do. I do not want to simply allow any PHP script to be able to access and modify any file on my server. How can I allow certain PHP files complete root access without compromising on security? If I could enable entire root access for just one PHP file, within that file, I can have multiple security checks, such as checking the IP address, session data checking, checking for a unique cookie, 2 step verification etc. I would even like to implement my own SSH console from within my CMS. Again, that must be 100% secure.

N.B. I am using Plesk Onyx Version 17.5.3 (webhost edition, VPS hosting and wildcard SSL) and Nginx with PHP-FPM 7.1.16. I do not use Apache, but it keeps re-enabling after I turn it off.

Comment: _Again, that must be 100% secure._ There is nothing like a 100% secure system.

Comment: @Dominik Maybe so, but I still need to make security my priority. If I do not proceed very carefully in solving the above, I could easily weaken my security and potentially open up vulnerabilities. However, if I can solve the above without compromising on security, I can already think of ways of making my system even more secure than it already is.

Comment: If security is your top concern, I would not use PHP at all. Furthermore, it seems a bit like you are reinventing the wheel, as you are developing a whole CMS on your own and want to implement your _own SSH console_. Maybe you should search for existing solutions to similar problems you are facing. The [Webmin](https://github.com/webmin/webmin) project for example, does execute commands as `root` based on the user's action within the web interface.

Comment: @Dominik My site relies on `PHP` as it is fully dynamic. My clients however, will not be able to directly write or upload PHP. I have created a framework called the `JHP Framework™` which will parse JHP code into safe PHP code and use my `JavaScript` libraries. This will allow my clients to write fully dynamic code. It is possible to do everything I plan to do securely and I have already made a great deal of progress, but there are so many potential vulnerabilities that I could open up if I am not extremely careful. That is why security has to be my top priority.

Answer (score 2):

this sounds like a bad idea - as keeping it simple is probably the best way to not compromise security etc. Automating things with cronjobs and having a command line scripts  to do things makes sense; but trying to implement 'ssh within the CMS' feels like it will add bloat to the app - and likely introduce a security risk.

You mention you are using PLESK - plesk does have a XML api - https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/api-rpc/about-xml-api/reference/managing-plesk-services.36910/ and https://github.com/plesk/api-examples

And https://github.com/plesk/ext-ssh-terminal

Can you not make use of some of the existing plesk functionality to achieve your aims and focus on the CMS?

Comment: I can make use of some of the existing Plesk functionality, but that does not really solve my problem. I have already had copy some of my Nginx files so that Plesk doesn't overwrite the changes, then replace `nginx.conf` with am `include`. My next task it to create a superuser only page on my CMS to search and view log files. I suppose I could work around the problem by storing log files in the directory just above the root, but that is not ideal and I have other reasons for wanting to give my superuser account root access.

Comment: TBH, if my superuser account gets compromised, my entire system is pretty much compromised anyway. If I could allow **only** my superuser account to have full root access of my system and access to an SSH console via my CMS, I can actually make my superuser account more secure than it already is, simply by making my superuser account require access to a PHP script that PHP cannot normally access. That means if a hacker was somehow able to execute malicious PHP code, they would fail to gain access to my superuser account.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using [PHPSeclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/) and here is a class I wrote to give PHP root access to any file. I will later make it even more secure by using SSH keys. I can now secure my system further by using `chmod` to make certain files root only read / write.

```
class Ssh
{
    private $ssh;
    private function connectTOSsh()
    {
        if (!self::$ssh)
        {
            $path = $pathTo/phpseclib/';
            require $path.'vendor/autoload.php';
            require $path.'phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php';
            self::$ssh = new \phpseclib\Net\SSH2('www.mysite.com');
        }
        if (!self::$ssh->isConnected())
        {
            self::$ssh->setTimeout(10);
            self::$ssh->login('username', 'password');
        }
    }

    public function restartNginx()
    {
        self::connectTOSsh();
        // TODO
    }

    public function getFileContents($path)
    {
        self::connectTOSsh();
        return self::$ssh->exec('cd /'.PHP_EOL.'cat '.$path);
    }

    public function writeToFile($path, $contents)
    {
        self::connectTOSsh();
        $tempFile = $pathTo.'temp/'.basename($path);
        file_put_contents($tempFile, $contents);
        self::$ssh->exec('cd /'.PHP_EOL.'mv '.$tempFile.' '.$path);
    }
}
```